# Why people in Germany don't lock their doors?

Tags: monster

In anime *Monster*, it's common to see people enter other's houses just by opening a door (without a key). Example: episodes #7, #12.

Why is that?

Comment: I haven't seen the anime, but if someone's home, why lock? (I'm German btw)

Comment: What kind of 'locking' are we talking about here? As another German, when I get home, of course I don't leave the door open, I do close it, but I don't lock it - neither do I know anyone who does while they are in. Since the doors don't have handles on the outside, you would still need a key to get in?

Answer (score 2):

There is no definitive answer to your question, however here are two points which may answer your question, between the two.

1) The people in question deem the area they live in safe enough to leave their doors unlocked, therefore walking in without a key would be simple.
**For example** it was a common game with us children where I lived to open a persons door and run away. (I was young, we did stupid stuff). As well as the fact that I and my family leave our doors unlocked when we are home.

2) They forgot to lock it. This isn't as common though also happens. If a person is not a complete safety-enthusiast with a checklist of things to do to ensure their safety, they are bound to forget to lock one time or another.